# How to make a generator generate a dataset of tuples (x, y) with x and y being numpy arrays?

Tags: python, keras, tuples, generator

I am trying to implement a neural network using keras.fit_generator() function. I have implemented the generator function that yields x, y where x is the data and y is the ground truth for the result and both are (156, 156, 156) numpy arrays. However, when I try to feed the data I get an error that says "Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)`. Found: tf.Tensor".

When I checked what I obtain when I create my dataset using the generator function and iterate through it, and what I am getting is indeed a tf.Tensor. However, I couldn't figure out how to make it return a tuple instead of a tf.Tensor with shape (1, 2, 156, 156, 156). What should I do to get a tuple of (x, y)?

For simplicity, I used the following generator function that is supposed to yield (x, y):

```
def tuple_fun():
    for _ in range(10):
        x = np.random.rand(156,156,156)
        y = np.random.rand(156,156,156)
        yield tuple((x, y))
```

I generated the dataset with the following piece of code:

```
def dataset_generator(batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: tuple_fun(), 
                                               output_types=tf.int8, 
                                               output_shapes = (2, 156, 156, 156)).batch(batch_size)
    return dataset
```

Then I tried feeding the data into a neural network via keras.fit_generator() as follows:

```
test_batch_size = 1

test_dataset = dataset_generator(test_batch_size)

iterator = iter(test_dataset)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(input_shape=(156, 156, 156, 1),
            filters=5, padding="same", kernel_size=3,
            activation='relu',
            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal()))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(decay=0.002))
model.fit_generator(iterator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=1)
```

And I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-e1055a8161e6> in <module>
     26 
     27 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(decay=0.002))
---> 28 model.fit_generator(iterator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=1)

~/anaconda3/envs/condaEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1513         shuffle=shuffle,
   1514         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
-> 1515         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
   1516 
   1517   def evaluate_generator(self,

~/anaconda3/envs/condaEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, steps_name, **kwargs)
    211     step = 0
    212     while step < target_steps:
--> 213       batch_data = _get_next_batch(generator, mode)
    214       if batch_data is None:
    215         if is_dataset:

~/anaconda3/envs/condaEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in _get_next_batch(generator, mode)
    363       raise ValueError('Output of generator should be '
    364                        'a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` '
--> 365                        'or `(x, y)`. Found: ' + str(generator_output))
    366 
    367   if len(generator_output) < 1 or len(generator_output) > 3:

ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)`. Found: tf.Tensor(
[[[[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    ...
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

   [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    ...
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

   [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    ...
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

   ...

   [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    ...
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

   [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    ...
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

   [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    ...
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]]


  [[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    ...
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

   [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    ...
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

   [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    ...
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

   ...

   [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    ...
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

   [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    ...
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

   [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    ...
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]]]], shape=(1, 2, 156, 156, 156), dtype=int8)
```

How can I solve this problem? This was my first question in stackoverflow so I hope I didn't do anything wrong. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you created generator `dataset_generator` and you create `test_dataset` but you don't use it in any other line of code. In `fit_generator` you don't use this generator too. You have some `iterator` in `fit_generator` but I don't see its definition in code.

Comment: You are right, I edited the initial post. Thanks for the warning.